# Any way to detect who all use iPhones in the phone contact list using iMessage related or some similar logic?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, imessage

When I send a sms msg to a friend in my phone book which also uses an iPhone, the message goes as iMessage by default.

Using the reverse logic, is it somehow possible to programatically  figure out a list of people in my phonebook who use an iPhone?

Actually I have built an iPhone app and I want to provide a feature to let the user share the info about the app with her other iPhone friends if she likes the app. Now since non iPhone friends have no interest with the msg coz they cant use the app, it makes sense to provide the user a list of only iPhone friends whom she can fwd her msg if she wants to. Therefore I want to provide a list of iPhone users from her phonebook only and then let her iMessage them.

How can I achive this?

Comment: This isn't a definitive answer, but may be a start - when a user enters a new contact on their iPhone, they can set the type of the phone number. I think the default types are "mobile," "home," "work," and "iPhone." Is it possible to get the type from the Address Book API? If so, that might give you a clue as to who has an iPhone and who doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your post several times and can't see a definite question. But I'll try it:

> Is it possible to find out, which of my friends are using an iPhone?

Yes and no. If you want to show only persons who downloaded the app, then it's totally possible, but if you want to find this out just by their phone numbers and using official Frameworks it's impossible to reach this.

> Is it possible to find out, which of my friends are using iMessage?

No, except they all download your app and enter if they're using iMessage or not.

*Again: If you want to get a list of your friends which are using an iPhone, they would need to download your app which collects the data. (It's called WhatsApp)*